# Specifying font size in a \newcommand?

Tags: fontsize, marginpar

I'm typing up a document in which I'd like to the margin's note font to be footnote size. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{outlines,marginnote}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=5cm, right=0.75cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=4.6cm, marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\mn}{\marginnote}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\Large \underline{Chapter 8 \textsc{Lipids}}  
\end{flushleft}

\section*{Lipids}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
  \1 What is a lipid? \mn{{\footnotesize How's it different from the other functional groups?}}
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

As it can be seen from my MWE, I had to specify the font size while making the margin note, but I want `\footnotesize` to assumed automatically. I'm thinking this can be done by modifying my `\newcommand` for margin note. I tried playing around with it, but nothing worked. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: See the [help on `\newcommand` and/or `\renewcommand`](http://www.ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-18.html) page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation of `marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) is your friend:

```
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{marginnote,letltxmacro}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize}
\LetLtxMacro\mn\marginnote
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
 What is a lipid? \mn{How's it different from the other functional groups?}
\end{document}
```

With the package [`outlines.sty`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/outlines) it also works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{outlines,marginnote,letltxmacro}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=5cm, right=0.75cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=4.6cm, marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}
\reversemarginpar
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize}
\LetLtxMacro\mn\marginnote
%\newcommand{\mn}{\marginnote}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\Large \underline{Chapter 8 \textsc{Lipids}}  
\end{flushleft}

\section*{Lipids}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
  \1 What is a lipid? \mn{{\footnotesize How's it different from the other functional groups?}}
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Added `letltxmacro`. Thanks to Werner for his comment.

Comment: [`outlines`](http://ctan.org/pkg/outlines) is not included in TeX Live, but it is included in MiKTeX.

Comment: @Werner: I downloaded the file from CTAN ;-) But the package has a small bug. It calls `ProvideClass`

Comment: Since `\marginnote` takes optional arguments, better to use `\LetLtxMacro{\mn}{\marginnote}` from the [`letltxmacro` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro).

Comment: @Werner: You are right.

Comment: @Marco: Although I liked Ben's fix since it was quick and easy (at least for my level of LaTeX), I decided to go with yours since it worked and I also learned a bit more about LaTeX. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could try `\newcommand{\mn}[1]{\marginnote{\footnotesize #1}}`.  That would work, but Marco's solution is better.

Comment: Sorry but with this solution you can't use the optional argument of `\marginnote`. (`\marginnote[left]{right}[voffset]`)

Comment: @Marco, true -- but the usage in the question above didn't indicate optional arguments, and seemed to be looking for a `\newcommand` approach.  As I said, your solution is better, since `\marginnote` includes a font hook.

Comment: You can use `\newcommand{\mn}[2][]{\marginnote[\footnotesize #1]{\footnotesize #2}}`